# WifiManager.enableNetwork Fails to connect

Tags: java, android, wifimanager

I am facing a problem in connecting to a specific network(say A), through code.

My code snippet is :

> tmpConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
>
> tmpConfig.BSSID = sBSSID;
>
> tmpConfig.SSID = sSSID;
>
> tmpConfig.status =WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
>
> int netId =wifiManager.addNetwork(tmpConfig);
>
> return wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId,true);

But, I keep getting false and the log is as follows :

> E/wpa_supplicant( 7983): Line 0: failed to parse ssid 'A'.
>
> D/MYWIFI  (8191): false

Has anyone faced this problem earlier, and knows a solution?

Thanks,
Pravein

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
tmpConfig.SSID = sSSID;
```

assign as

```
tmpConfig.SSID = "\""+ sSSID +"\"";
```

Answer (score 1):

In addion to Amitku's answer, You may have to run

```
wifiManager.disconnect();
```

before attempting to trying to enable your other network.